# Save view in Navigation Drawer change

Tags: android

I'm working with the navigation drawer for switching between fragments. In one of those fragments I'm creating a map with markers and some data. In my current code, the views are re created after navigating to other fragments (going map, then to profile, and then back to the map, the map is created again). How can I save the map for being destroyed? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is every time you display a new `Fragment` (new page), use `FragmentTransaction.add`, and specify a tag (unique for each `Fragment`). And then, when you want to display a `Fragment` previously created, use `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag` to retrieve it.

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try that